# How to store current Geo-location in Web SQL using JavaScript - Cordova

Tags: cordova

I'm trying to store `Geolocation` in google chrome browser storage using `sq-lite websql` ...

```js
var db;

window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('btnSave').addEventListener('click', saveData);
  db = window.openDatabase("geolocation", "1.0", "Technorigins", 200000);
}

function saveData(e) {
  db.transaction(saveRecord, onSuccessdb, onErrordb);
}

function saveRecord(transaction) {
  var latitude = document.getElementById('latitude').value;
  var longitude = document.getElementById('longitude').value;
  transaction.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS geol_cordova (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, latitude TEXT NOT NULL, longitude TEXT NOT NULL) ');
  var sql = "INSERT INTO geol_cordova (latitude,longitude) VALUES ('" + latitude + "', '" + longitude + "')";

  transaction.executeSql(sql);
  transaction.executeSql("SELECT * FROM geol_cordova", [], onSuccessdb, onErrordb);
  alert(sql);
}

function getSuccess(transaction, result) {
  var rows = result.rows;
  for (var x = 0; x < rows.length; x++) {
    var latitude = result.rows[x].Latitude;
    var longitude = result.rows[x].Longitude;
    var out = "<li>" + latitude + "<br/>" + longitude + "</li>";
    document.getElementById('geolo').innerHTML += out;
  }

  $('#geolo').listview('refresh');
}

function getError(e) {
  alert(e);
}

function onSuccessdb() {
  alert("Location Saved");
}

function onErrordb(error) {
  alert("SQL error: ");
}

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

var watchID = null;

function onDeviceReady() {

  var options = {
    timeout: 30000,
    maximumAge: 60000
  };
  watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);
}

function onSuccess(position) {
  var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
  element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: ' + position.coords.latitude + '<br />' +
    'Longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude + '<br />' +
    'GPS Position: ' + distance('23.054996', '72.595171', position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude, 'ME') + ' Metres' +
    '<hr />' + element.innerHTML;
  document.getElementById('latitude').value = position.coords.latitude;
  document.getElementById('longitude').value = position.coords.longitude;
}

function onError(error) {
  alert('code: ' + error.code + '\n' +
    'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}

function distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, unit) {
  var radlat1 = Math.PI * lat1 / 180
  var radlat2 = Math.PI * lat2 / 180
  var theta = lon1 - lon2
  var radtheta = Math.PI * theta / 180
  var dist = Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
  dist = Math.acos(dist)
  dist = dist * 180 / Math.PI
  dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515
  if (unit == "K") {
    dist = dist * 1.609344
  }
  if (unit == "N") {
    dist = dist * 0.8684
  }
  if (unit == "ME") {
    dist = dist * 1.609344 * 1000
  }
  return dist
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
  <title>geolocation watchPosition</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Database Storage</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
      <p id="geolocation">Watching geolocation...</p>
      <input type="hidden" id="latitude" value="" />
      <input type="hidden" id="longitude" value="" />
      <button id="btnSave" type="submit">Save</button>
      <ul id="geolo" data-role="listview">
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/overrides.css" />
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For Web SQL Database, we need to create the database structure if it doesn't exist. openDatabase fortunately creates the database automatically if it doesn't exist, and, likewise, we use the SQL phrase "if not exists" to ensure the new checkins table is not overridden if it is already present. We have to define the structure of the data upfront, i.e. the name and type of each column in the checkins table. Each row will represent a single checkin.

```js
this.db = openDatabase('geomood', '1.0', 'Geo-Mood Checkins', 8192);
this.db.transaction(function(tx) {
  tx.executeSql("create table if not exists " +
    "checkins(id integer primary key asc, time integer, latitude float," +
              "longitude float, mood string)",
    [],
    function() { console.log("siucc"); }
  );
});
```

```js
setup: function(handler) {
  requestFileSystem(
    window.PERSISTENT,
    1024*1024,
    function(fs) {
      fs.root.getDirectory(
        "checkins",
        {}, // no "create" option, so this is a read op
        function(dir) {
          checkinsDir = dir;
          handler();
        },
        function() {
          fs.root.getDirectory(
            "checkins",
            {create: true},
            function(dir) {
              checkinsDir = dir;
              handler();
            },
            onError
          );
        }
      );
    },
    function(e) {
      console.log("error "+e.code+"");
    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
   var db;
            
        window.onload=function()
        {
            document.getElementById('btnSave').addEventListener('click', saveData);
            db = window.openDatabase("geolocation",  "1.0", "Technorigins", 200000);
   
        }
        
        function saveData(e)
        {
           
            
           
            db.transaction(saveRecord, onSuccessdb, onErrordb);
   
        }
            
        function saveRecord(transaction)
        {
            var latitude= document.getElementById('latitude').value;
            var longitude= document.getElementById('longitude').value;
  
            transaction.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS geol_cordova (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, latitude TEXT NOT NULL, longitude TEXT NOT NULL) ');
            
            var sql= "INSERT INTO geol_cordova (latitude,longitude) VALUES ('" + latitude +"', '" + longitude + "')";
           transaction.executeSql(sql); 
     alert(sql);
     transaction.executeSql("SELECT * FROM geol_cordova", [], getSuccess, getError);
        }
  
   function getSuccess(tx, result)
        {
            var rows = result.rows;
            for(var x=0; x< rows.length; x++){
                var latitude = result.rows[x].latitude;
                var longitude = result.rows[x].longitude;
                var out = "<li>" + latitude + "<br/>" + longitude + "</li>";
                document.getElementById('geolo').innerHTML += out;
            }
            
            $('#geolo').listview('refresh');
        }
            
        function onSuccessdb()
        {
            alert("Location Saved");
        }
            
        function onErrordb(error)
        {
            alert("SQL error: ");
        }
  //-----------------
  function getError(e)
        {
            alert(e);
        }
            
        
  
  
   // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    var watchID = null;

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
     // Throw an error if no update is received every 30 seconds
     var options = { timeout: 30000 , maximumAge : 60000};
     watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);
    }

    // onSuccess Geolocation
    //
    function onSuccess(position) {
     var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
     element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '  + position.coords.latitude      + '<br />' +
          'Longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude     + '<br />' +
          'GPS Position: ' + distance('23.054996', '72.595171', position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude, 'ME') + ' Metres'  +
          '<hr />'      + element.innerHTML;
          document.getElementById('latitude').value=position.coords.latitude;
          document.getElementById('longitude').value=position.coords.longitude;
    }

    // onError Callback receives a PositionError object
    //
    function onError(error) {
     alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
        'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }
    
    function distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, unit) {
    var radlat1 = Math.PI * lat1/180
    var radlat2 = Math.PI * lat2/180
    var theta = lon1-lon2
    var radtheta = Math.PI * theta/180
    var dist = Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
    dist = Math.acos(dist)
    dist = dist * 180/Math.PI
    dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515
    if (unit=="K") { dist = dist * 1.609344 }
    if (unit=="N") { dist = dist * 0.8684 }
    if (unit=="ME") { dist = dist * 1.609344 * 1000}
    return dist
    }
```

```html
<div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header"><h1>Database Storage</h1></div>
        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
  <p id="geolocation">Watching geolocation...</p>
  <input type="hidden" id="latitude" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" id="longitude" value="" />
  <button id="btnSave" type="submit">Save</button>
  <ul id="geolo" data-role="listview">
        </ul>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/overrides.css" />
  </div><!-- main-->
        </div><!-- page -->
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer sir :)